# Is the statement also true in infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-independence

I am trying to prove that:

"A basis is equivalent to a maximal linearly independent set"

I am wondering if this statement is true for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Can someone help me answer this question please?

Comment: What's the definition of basis that you are working with?

Comment: The confusion might be that in the infinite-dimensional case, you need Zorn's Lemma or similar to conclude that such a maximal set (and thus a basis) must exist.

Comment: @anomaly how is that? are you saying that the solution below is incomplete? Can you add your solution below please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a basis as a linearly independent set which spans the entire space, then the answer is yes.

Suppose $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$. Let $B \subseteq B' \subseteq V$ be arbitrary. Then for any $b \in B'\setminus B$ by definition of a basis we have $b \in \operatorname{span} B$ so $B'$ cannot be linearly independent. Therefore $B$ is a maximal linearly independent set in $V$.

Conversely, let $B\subseteq V$ be a maximal linearly independent set in $V$. Let $x \in V$ be arbitrary. If $x \notin \operatorname{span} B$, then $B\cup \{x\}$ would be a linearly independent set containing $B$, contradicting the maximality of $B$. Therefore $x \in \operatorname{span} B$. Since $x \in V$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\operatorname{span} B = V$ so $B$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: So this statement is also true if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: I did not understand what is exactly arbitrary in the following statement "Let $B \subseteq B' \subseteq V$ be arbitrary" ..... could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Secretly Yes, it's true for all vector spaces $V$. In that sentence the set $B'$ is meant to represent an arbitrary subset of $V$ which contains $B$. The conclusion is that every such set $B'$ is necessarily linearly dependent. Therefore, a linearly independent set which strictly contains $B$ cannot exist so $B$ is maximal.

Comment: have you seen the comment of anomaly above? does this comment affects your solution?

Comment: @Secretly Yes, the proof of existence of a basis for an infinite-dimensional vector space is nontrivial and depends on the axiom of choice. It doesn't affect my solution though, I'm only showing that a set $B$ is a basis if and only if it is a maximal linearly independent set, I'm not claiming such a set $B$ exists.

Comment: Oh I see, so your proof is correct anyway whether we are speaking about finite or infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @Secretly Yes, the cardinality is not used in the proof.